# Does django rest-framework force the foreign key to point to a primary key?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In django it  is absolutely fine to define a  foreign key which point to a unique key column  instead of primary  key. For example

```
class Cluster(models.Model):
    _id = models.UUIDField(unique=True, null=False, default=uuid.uuid1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, null=False)

class Node(models.Model):
    _id = models.UUIDField(unique=True, null=False, default=uuid.uuid1)
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=False, unique=True)
    cluster = models.ForeignKey(Cluster, on_delete=models.PROTECT, to_field='_id', db_constraint=False)
```

Please  note  that the _id field here is not a pk field.

But in django rest-framework when define a serializer

```
class NodeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cluster_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        source='cluster', queryset=models.Cluster.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = models.Node
        fields = ('_id', 'name', 'ip', 'cluster_ip', 'cluster_id')
```

The serializer will think that the cluster_id is  pointing to the pk field  of cluster.

Is there  any way I can tell serializer that cluster_id is not pointing to pk?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield):

```
cluster_id = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        source='cluster', slug_field='_id', queryset=models.Cluster.objects.all())
```